# Turing machine that accepts when a string of x's is followed by the same number of y's

Tags: turing-machines

I need to draw a machine's states that accepts (writes a 1) when it reads a string of x's that is followed by the same number of y's and would reject (writes a 0) for anything else. It has to work for all possible input tapes. For example, it would accept xxxyyy but would reject xxyyy and xx. I cannot figure out how to keep track of the number of x's that are read in, and then count the y's that follow without creating an infinite chain. This is what I have come up with for the Turing Machine:

start: State 0, read: x, next: State 1, write: 0, move: right; start: State 1, read: y, next: halt, write: 1, move: neutral

Answer (score 0):

A Turing Machine to accept the language $L = \{x^n y^n | n > 0\}$

```
On input string w
    while there are unmarked x's, do:
         Mark the left most x
         Scan right till the leftmost unmarked y
         if there is no such y then crash
    Mark the leftmost y
done
Check to see that there are no unmarked y's;
    if there are then crash
accept
```

There may be other ways. Better refer to any standard textbook as this problem is quite common.

Edit: The Turing Machine will have the following description.

$Q=\{q_0,q_1,q_2,q_3,q_4\}$,

$F=\{q_4\}$,

$\sum=\{x,y\}$,

$\tau=\{x,y,1,0,\square\}$

where all symbols have their usual meanings. Work out the details on your own.

Comment: Thanks @Sagnik  That algorithm makes sense to me, but I'm still confused on how you would draw out the state machines.